# Advanced sendgrid settings - API for PHP

Tags: php, email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I need to know how to configure sendgrid v3 to send emails using the WEB API. I am using the following code but it shows me an error:

```
$request_body = json_decode('{
              "asm": {
              "content": [
                 {
                    "type": "text/html", 
                    "value": "'. $body .'"
                 }
              ], 
              "from": {
                 "email": "'. $sender_email .'", 
                 "name": "'. $sender_name .'"
              }, 
              "personalizations": [
                 {
                    "bcc": [
                      {
                         "email": "'. $receiver_email .'", 
                         "name": "'. $receiver_name .'"
                      }
                    ],
                    "headers": {
                      "X-Accept-Language": "en", 
                      "X-Mailer": "MailerKobsa"
                    }, 
                    "send_at": 1409348513, 
                    "subject": "'. $subject .'", 
                    "substitutions": {
                      "id": "substitutions", 
                      "type": "object"
                    }, 
                    "to": [
                      {
                         "email": "'. $receiver_email .'", 
                         "name": "'. $receiver_name .'"
                      }
                    ]
                 }
              ], 
              "reply_to": {
                 "email": "'. $sender_email .'", 
                 "name": "'. $sender_name .'"
              }, 
              "send_at": 1409348513, 
              "subject": "'. $subject .'"
            }');
```

But I get the following error:

```
415array(9) { [0]=> string(36) "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type " [1]=> string(14) "Server: nginx " [2]=> string(36) "Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 23:53:37 GMT " [3]=> string(31) "Content-Type: application/json " [4]=> string(19) "Content-Length: 92 " [5]=> string(23) "Connection: keep-alive " [6]=> string(22) "X-Frame-Options: DENY " [7]=> string(1) " " [8]=> string(0) "" } {"errors":[{"message":"Content-Type should be application/json.","field":null,"help":null}]}415array(9) { [0]=> string(36) "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type " [1]=> string(14) "Server: nginx " [2]=> string(36) "Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 23:53:38 GMT " [3]=> string(31) "Content-Type: application/json " [4]=> string(19) "Content-Length: 92 " [5]=> string(23) "Connection: keep-alive " [6]=> string(22) "X-Frame-Options: DENY " [7]=> string(1) " " [8]=> string(0) "" } {"errors":[{"message":"Content-Type should be application/json.","field":null,"help":null}]}
```

I must mention that I have tried sending emails using the "simple" version that is in Github, I have correctly configured my apikey and I have been able to send emails in the simple version with no problems. But in the advanced version I need to add more information like the name of the recipient and not just his email.

I do not use campaigns, do not extract information from a database. I extract the information from a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error: `"message":"Content-Type should be application/json."` Did you make sure you're declaring the Content-Type header properly?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed changing the header.

If you are using CURL from PHP, it will be a great help
My code solved:

```
$authorization = 'authorization: Bearer '.trim($apiKey);
$header = [
'Content-Type: application/json',
$authorization
];
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

I don't know why the array function doesn't work :

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: 
application/json',
$authorization));
```